# How do these UK certificates convert to the US?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, international-students, certification

Due to the pandemic, many UK universities have expanded opportunities for people to potentially earn a UK degree without leaving the US. I see several types of programs listed. All say they require "3 units", requiring one year of study:

- Undergraduate certificate
- Undergraduate diploma
- Undergraduate advanced diploma
- Postgraduate certificate
- Postgraduate diploma

How do these translate to the US? Is a "undergraduate diploma" considered equal to a "bachelor's degree"?

Answer (score 3):

The different levels of UK higher education conform to the internationally agreed Bologna Process and the corresponding levels can be read in the [regulators documentation](https://www.qaa.ac.uk/docs/qaa/quality-code/bologna-process-in-he#:%7E:text=The%20Bologna%20Process%20proposes%20that,across%20higher%20education%20in%20Europe.).

An undergraduate certificate is one year (the fresher's year) of a three year Bachelor degree and also known as level 4 study.

An undergraduate diploma is the first and second years (freshers plus sophomore) or level 4 + 5.

The others also map to the same thing. An advanced diploma is usually at diploma level but more advanced material (perhaps a professional qualification).

Postgraduate certificate would be the first trimester of a Masters degree (i.e. 1/3rd)
Postgraduate diplomas would be a Masters without a completed dissertation.

Comment: In your third paragraph, do you mean "the first two years", rather than "the second two years"?

Comment: Thanks, Brian.  Although they weren't on OP's list, something else that's worth pointing out (because of the potential confusion) is that a foundation _degree_ is a level 5 qualification, but a foundation _year_ is a course of education at level 3.